# how to complete all pending SELECT statements?

Tags: c, sqlite

The [SQLite wiki page for "database is locked"](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked) says:

> Sometimes people think they have finished with a `SELECT` statement because `sqlite3_step()` has returned `SQLITE_DONE`. But the `SELECT` is not really complete until `sqlite3_reset()` or `sqlite3_finalize()` have been called.
>   As of check-in [3902] (2007-05-02 after version 3.3.17) this is now allowed for `CREATE` statement.

I can, of course, close and reopen the database, but this would invalidate all prepared statements. Does there exist another way that would not involve me tracking all pending `SELECT` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can, of course, close and reopen the database, but this would invalidate all prepared statements. Does there exist another way that would not involve me tracking all pending SELECT statements?

SQLite already tracks all your prepared statements, and it provides [`sqlite3_next_stmt()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/next_stmt.html) as a mechanism by which you can traverse its list.  There is also [`sqlite3_stmt_busy()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt_busy.html) by which you can test whether a statement is holding a transaction open, but that doesn't help you recognize statements that have run to completion, and thus are not associated with a live transaction, but still have database resources allocated to them as a result of not having been finalized or reset.

Here's a way you could reset all prepared statements currently known to SQLite:

```
    sqlite3 *db = /* ... */
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    /* ensure that there is no open transaction; will fail harmlessly if
       there already is none */
    sqlite3_exec(db, "rollback", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /* Clean up any outstanding prepared statements */
    for (stmt = sqlite3_next_stmt(db, NULL); stmt; stmt = sqlite3_next_stmt(db, stmt)) {
        int result = sqlite3_reset(stmt);
        /* handle errors ... */
    }
```

It should not be harmful to reset statements that don't need it.

With that said, you SHOULD track your currently-running statements, and ensure that you reset them when you're done with the current set of results they are serving.  This requires a bit of discipline, but it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Why is ROLLBACK necessary?

Comment: @user1095108, Every transaction must either commit or rollback.  It is dangerous to blindly commit, without knowing what you're committing.  If there is indeed a transaction open on the DB connection then it is safer to rollback.  If all your statements are `SELECT`s then it doesn't matter.  With that said, the explicit rollback is mostly a matter of form and defensive coding.  The SQLite docs are unclear about what happens if you try to reset a statement that is participating in an open transaction.